# PHP - How should GPS LOCATION Regular expression look like?

Tags: php, regex

I'm gonna have to learn to use regular expressions soon, but now I just need to know how should a check for "50.080215,14.393983" GPS format look like, thanks, Mike.

Comment: Is that lat,long or long,lat?

Comment: See http://www.insyte-solutions.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=68:validating-and-parsing-gps-sentences&catid=37:articles&Itemid=54

Answer (score 1):

You want to find two decimal numbers separated by a comma (and maybe whitespace?) in a string?

```
$pattern = "/(?P<lat>(\d+(\.\d+)?)),\s*(?P<lon>(\d+(\.\d+)?))/";
```

This assumes that the fractional portion of each number may not be present if not needed and places no constraints on the number of digits of precision. Depending on your input corpus this may match more often than you want. With a better specification a tighter pattern could be constructed. For example if we specify that latitude will run form -90 to 90 inclusive and longitude will run from -180 to 180 inclusive and both may have up to 6 digits of precision we can construct this pattern:

```
$pattern = "/(?P<lat>-?([1-8]?[1-9]|[1-9]0)(\.\d{1,6})?)(?P<lon>-?(1?[1-7][1-9]|1?[1-8]0|[1-9]?[0-9])(\.\d{1,6})?)/";
```

There is a slight bug in this specification in that it will match "90.999999,180.999999" which is outside the hypothetical spec. Correcting this left as an exercise for the reader.